# What is a star child?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shaman

In Pathfinder, one of the effects of the 20th-level capstone ability of the [Heavens](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/spirits/heavens/) spirit Shaman is that if you ever die, you are reborn/reincarnated as a "star child".

> If she dies, she’s reborn 3 days later in the form of a star child, maturing over the course of 7 days (as reincarnate).

(Not to be confused with the [starchild trait](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/religion-traits/starchild/), which gives you +4 to survival checks to avoid getting lost.)

What is a star child in the context of this ability?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A "star child" is not defined by the game

This term first appeared on the *Advanced Players Guide*, under the oracle mysteries, then getting repeated on the *Advanced Class Guides* for the shaman class.

There is speculation that it is simply a "child born under the stars", with no mother and father, but still a normal person. This is inspired on the tale of the goddess [Desna](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Desna), which is said to have been born from star dust. Others say that it is inspired by the fetus at the end of 2001 Space Odyssey movie ([video spoiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6umxthz1Ys)).

James Jacobs (Creative Director) [has said that this is merely flavor](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l366?Oracle-of-Heavens-and-Star-Child#3):

> Correct. "Star child" is merely a flavorful way of saying "A reincarnated oracle." And an easter egg to 2001, I suppose.

The ability does exactly what the text of [Reincarnate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/) says it does, with the exceptions noted on the ability.

Answer (score -2):

While looking at the [Half-Elf](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-elf/) alternative racial abilities, I noticed that one of them is starchild.

> **Starchild:** Some half-elves descend from elves who are not from this world, but rather visitors from another world, plane, or dimension. Half-elves with this trait gain Psychic Sensitivity as a bonus feat at 1st level. This racial trait replaces adaptability.

It cites the *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game: Horror Adventures* book (PZO 1135) as its source.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but this doesn’t appear to be “in the context of this [shaman] ability” that is the topic.

Comment: While true, this does add some more background on possible stories for a "starchild". Also the quote from James Jacob specifically references a reincarnated Oracle, not a shaman. Is this term then to just be applied to all reincarnated beings?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Thank you V2Blast. I was unsure what that citation was for.

Comment: “Is this term then to just be applied to all reincarnated beings?” No, of course not. It’s a term that has been used to mean all kinds of things already. But the question is what it means in one specific use, not what all of its unrelated uses mean.

Comment: @Ray to clarify, the Heavens spirit inherited abilities from the Heavens oracle mystery, hence why they are similar in theme and concept. So, though JJ is talking about oracles, its worth noting that shamans are a hybrid of oracles+druids and his design insight does have some weight.